# How to show direct Images instead of images in a layout in intro slider

Tags: java, android

I want to show three screens in my intro slider, right now i am doing that by showing three layouts how to show directly images not using layouts. Below is my code

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }
   layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.welcome_slide1,
                R.layout.welcome_slide2,
                R.layout.welcome_slide3};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
  ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
  iv.setImageResource(images[position]);
  container.addView(iv);
  return iv;
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error at ImageView iv = new ImageView(context); what is context here?

Comment: i did but i don't have enough reputation as soon as i get enough it gets upvoted